# Using :not selector in tandem with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to select all `a` hrefs that do not have the class `.agency`:

```
$("#content-listing").on("click", "a:not(li.agency a)",
    function () {
        $("#content-listing").hide();
    });
```

I also tried:

```
$("#content-listing").on("click", "a.not('li.agency a')", function () {
    $("#content-listing").hide();
});
```

Comment: Because my `li`has the class `agency`and I want to select all `hrefs`in the div except `li.agency a`

Comment: ohhh, you should have said that. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11042983/601179)

Comment: @Blen, I don't think you had to delete your answer, it was the right answer to the question, he just changed the requirements in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your comment:

> Because my **li** has the class **agency** and I want to select all links in the `<div>` except **li.agency a**

Then Use this:

```
$("#content-listing").on("click", "li:not(.agency) a", function () {
    $("#content-listing").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it without `:not`:

```
$("#content-listing").on("click", "a[class!='agency'])", function(){
    ...
});
```

Note that it will work only if all those `.agency` anchors have only this class.